# guidata(hObject, handles); Why do we really need it?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

Recently I've been working a lot with the `Matlab GUI GUIDE`.

When I build a GUI, each time I write a `callback function`, I have to add at the end of the function this line: `guidata(hObject, handles);` for example:

```
function someFunction_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
.... %implementation
........
guidata(hObject, handles);  <------------
```

Now I want to understand why I'm adding this line each time I have a function that is related to the GUI.

What really happens behind the scenes? What information does this struct hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using guidata is one way to read/store back the user data between callbacks. I typically do this

```
function reset_btn_tag_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

data = get(handles.figure1, 'UserData');
data.state = -1; %change my data
% etc... 
set(handles.figure1, 'UserData',data);  %save it back before return
```

Unless You read your data earlier using `myData=guidata(object_handle)` Then there is no point of doing `guidata(object_handle,myData)`

again, `guidata` is just an API for you to use to read/write your data back to the figure internals to be stored there between callbacks. If you do not modify your own data in a callback, there no need to use it. I'd put all my data in a `struct` becuase `guidata` works for one variable only.

So, if you do not modify anything in your data or handles as you show in your example, then no need to use it.